# How do I use an anonymous function within a class method in Python (closure)?

Tags: python, closures, anonymous-function

```
class Test:

    def somemethod(self):
        def write():
            print 'hello'

        write()

x = Test()
x.somemethod()
```

write() is a function that will be used several times through somemethod(). somemethod() is the only function within the class that will require it's use so it seems silly to define it outside of somemethod(). Closure seems like the way to go.

When I run that code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: somemethod() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is `self` getting passed to write()? :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use an anonymous function within a class method in Python (closure)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649239/how-do-i-use-an-anonymous-function-within-a-class-method-in-python-closure)

Comment: My connection to SO got messed up when I was trying to POST. Seems Chrome double POST'd. Sorry >.<

Comment: no worries. I've flagged the questions and one of the dupes will be removed or merged by a moderator shortly.

Comment: -1 for double post and not cleaning up

Answer (score 3):

I find it impossible to reproduce the problem you report:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...   def somemethod(self):
...     def write():
...       print 'hello'
...     write()
... 
>>> x = Test()
>>> x.somemethod()
hello
>>>
```

so I believe you must have done some transcription error, or something.  What do you see when you run exactly the code I'm showing here?  (Works identically in Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, on all platforms).

Comment: It seems my bug lied elsewhere... Thanks for clearing my head

Answer (score 0):

It also works for me:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def somemethod(self):
...         def write():
...             print 'hello'
...         write()
... 
>>> 
>>> x = Test()
>>> x.somemethod()
hello
>>>
```

I think you might be using tabs *and* spaces, or your identation is wrong